# What is this history window in vim called?

Tags: vim, misspelling

Sometime when I execute a vim command, a history like window appears out of nowhere.
Anyone knows what it does, what it's called and how to make it appear?

[image: Vim]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called the command-line window

```
:h command-line-window
```

You can bring it via `<c-f>` while on the prompt or `q:` in normal mode

```
:h q:
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have typed q: instead of :q